# No FBRequestConnection in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I can't find any references to `FBRequestConnection` (`FBRequestConnection.h`) in the FaceBook SDK for iOS (latest version, no ARC).

Am I missing something? I need this to accomplish "batch requests".

UPDATE:
Still no sign of `FBRequestConnection`. The batch requests though don't really need it anyway.
I was able to fire them without `FBRequestConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

See that [link](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

May be it will help

and these are the task of FBRequestConection in Facebook

```
– init
– initWithTimeout:
urlRequest property
urlResponse property
– addRequest:completionHandler:
– addRequest:completionHandler:batchEntryName:
– start
– cancel
+ startForMeWithCompletionHandler:
+ startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:
+ startForUploadPhoto:completionHandler:
+ startForPostStatusUpdate:completionHandler:
+ startForPostStatusUpdate:place:tags:completionHandler:
+ startForPlacesSearchAtCoordinate:radiusInMeters:resultsLimit:searchText:completionHandler:
+ startWithGraphPath:completionHandler:
+ startForPostWithGraphPath:graphObject:completionHandler:
+ startWithGraphPath:parameters:HTTPMethod:completionHandler:
```

Comment: Just did not need FBRequestConnection to do batch requests. Thats all.